# axios header interceptors are changing the payload as well

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using Axios interceptors to add a custom header to all outbound requests from my client in a React app.

I just noticed that this not only adds the header but also inherently changes the payload: more specifically, a JSON field we're passing as a string is implicitly being converted to a JSON object.

When I remove this code, the requests return to normal. I've looked through the axios source code and cannot understand where and why it would behave this way but it appears to be a bug in the way axios parses the data when you use header interceptors

Wondering if anyone else has experienced this before

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const customerId = getCustomerID();
  if (config?.headers && customerId){
    config.headers[HEADER] = customerId;
  }
  return config;
});
```

Any idea why Axios is implicitly touching the payload when it should only be adjusting the headers and whether this can be disabled?

Comment: Do you have an example of how the data is being changed? Also, which version of Axios are you using and what is `HEADER`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set the header no need to use an interceptor, use:

```
(() => {
  const customerId = getCustomerID();
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Customer-Id'] = customerId;
})()
```